# The slope and intercept of piecewise linear functions

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-optimization

If we have a function $f$ in the form:
$$f(x)=\sum_{j}^{N}c_j \min_i(a_{ij}x+b_{ij})$$
Question:

All of $ a_{ij}$ and $a_{ij}$ are known.

How can I find the slopes of $f$ as optimal as possible. $f$ also hase the form $f(x)=\min_i(A_i x+B_i)$.
How to find all of $A_i$ and $B_i$ efficiently???

I am considering to do it in matlab. Actually I did it in matlab, but I am not sure with the result.

Comment: These are actually Benders cuts and all of these functions are piecewise concave

Comment: **Hint:** Let  $\Delta_n$ be the unit simplex in $n$ dimensions. WLOG, assume your functions are defined in terms of "max" instead of "min", and note that $\underset{1 \le i \le n}{\text{max }}A_ix + b_i = \underset{y \in \Delta_n}{\text{max }}\langle y, Ax + b\rangle$. You can now use the Danskin-Bertsekas Theorem (Prop. A.22 of Bersekas' thesis) to get $\partial \underset{y \in \Delta_n}{\text{max }}\langle y, Ax + b\rangle = \mathrm{conv }\{1 \le i \le n| A_ix + b_i \text{ is a max component of }Ax + b\}$, which is isomorphic to a lower dimensional simplex (aka a *face* of $\Delta_n$).